# Invalid type for my controller

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, invalid

**Controller**

```
        for (Business_Card_Request_Price_c i: tempList) {

            tmpWrp.add(new BCRWrapper(i));

        }
```

I am receiving an error -

> Invalid type: Business_Card_Request_Price__c

. What must I do in order to generate the table, and be able to select individual prices from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line **192** in your class you are incorrectly referencing your custom object.

```
for (Business_Card_Request_Price_c i : tempList) {
    tmpWrp.add(new BCRWrapper(i));
}
```

For custom objects, the API must include a suffix of **two underscores** followed by a lowercase “c”.

Change your code to:

```
for (Business_Card_Request_Price__c i : tempList) {
    tmpWrp.add(new BCRWrapper(i));
}
```